# StarUML fails to open file with JavaScript error

Tags: class-diagram, staruml

I created a file in StarUML, and when I wanted to open it again, it gave me this message and the diagram did not open. How can I solve it?

[image: screenshot]

> Uncaught Exception: 
> TypeError: Error processing argument at index 1, conversion failure from undefined

I tried to open it a few times unsuccessfully.

Comment: The question is about packaged software, and off topic on SO. Suggest https://staruml.io/support/